# PHP Session Without Default Data

Tags: php, session, login-script, login-control

I want to create `php session` without db and without default data for user login. Because on this web anyone can login with any user and password, but I do not want him to login with the same user and password for the next login. May prevent one IP to login multiple times. Can someone help me?

Comment: Well, you can store the `IP` in the session, then check if it is the same one

Comment: where are you going to store who logged in from where?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer but I can't comment due to the reputation is less than 50 sorry for that.

I have a question for you how are you going to compare the first login user name and password to the second login. Where you going to store them in sessions but sessions get destroyed if the user close the browser he can relogin with the same username and password.

Or are going to use cookies to store the information ?

To prevent same IP with 2 logins you have store the IP in in session then compare it with every login.

I should look in to creating cookies than sessions but with out a database will be very tricky and hard.

Another thing your question has very limited information you should give the community much more details than that.